# SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays] in Eclipse plug-in devlopment

Tags: java, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I have plug-in project in which I am using

```
Display display = new Display(); // twice
```

this plug-in is working fine on Windows.

But when I run plug-in on Linux it throws an error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
Root exception:
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at com.test$OpenPage.run(test.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.wizards.AbstractRepositorySettingsPage$29.run(AbstractRepositorySettingsPage.java:1964)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

I have tested it on Windows 7/8.1/10 (working fine) and Ubuntu (not working)

Comment: in `run` method of `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec`by `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell()` i got shell and now `shell.getDisplay` works for me thnks Hermann and greg-449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for multiple `Display` objects varies between platforms. Looking at the source code this is not supported on Linux/GTK or macOS.

For full portability you need to stick to a single `Display` device. It is generally not necessary to use more than one.

Comment: Second `Display` is open from some action perform on first `Display` which opens a `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell`. I need both `Display` to open

Comment: I don't see why that requires another display. I have plenty of code using browsers in shells and they don't need another display. As the other answer says in an Eclipse plugin you should never create a display, **ever**

Comment: When I create 
 `display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();`
 `shell = new Shell(display);`
It gives `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access`

Comment: All SWT UI operations must be done on the single UI thread. If your code is not running on that thread use the `asyncExec` or `syncExec` methods of `Display` to execute a `Runnable` on the UI thread

Answer (score 4):

On some platforms, SWT does not support creating multiple displays.

However, plug-in code should not create a `Display` at all. During workbench startup, a display is created for you that you can access either through

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay()
```

or by obtaining the display from an existing widget, for example:

```java
void createControls(Composite parent) {
  Display display = parent.getDisplay();
  ...
}
```